# SQLAlchemy transaction isolation between workers and server

Tags: mysql, concurrency, sqlalchemy

I have the following problem, using SQLALchemy 0.7.8, Flask-SQLAlchemy 0.16 and MySQL 5.5.

I have a cron script running on server A which queries the table T for the id of all rows matching a particular status, send those ids to a broker, which distributes it to workers across many other machines.

A worker gets the id, query that table T and some other tables for data, update the table to mark that id as being processed, commit the transaction, and send those to a server X through a REST API.

Once that server X gets the job done, it sends the result to a callback in another REST API in another server Y. The server Y does some processing and save the result back on table T. After committing that, it sends the id to another worker, which might be the same who got it on the first step, and that worker is now supposed to get some other data and send back to another service, but it won't do any update on this step.

The problem is, on this last step, the worker doesn't get the data updated by server Y through the callback, it gets data from before that update.

I figured the worker still is on the session it used to send the data to server X first, and that isn't refreshed because no commits or rollbacks happened between that and the next time it queries data, when server Y is called back.

What is the adequate solution in this case? So far I tried calling session.commit() in the beginning of the task, before the workers queries data, and it seems to be working, but I'm not so sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the long running transaction, and although it could be fixed by managing the session instead of using Flask global db.session, the proper way to do it under Flask-SQLAlchemy is to create a new context for each task call.

So, instead of:

```
def task(args):
    session = Session(engine)
    try:
       ... do stuff here
        session.commit()
    finally:
        session.close()
```

It just needs:

```
def task(args):
    with app.app_context():
        ... do stuff here
```

Related discussion here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/yXSroyVNKYM

Answer (score 0):

discussion for this issue took place over at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/yXSroyVNKYM.

Comment: You are quick... I was planning to do that by answering here when the discussion is over.